# Framework to run processes in the "cloud"

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, digital-ocean

I am currently looking for a solution to run arbitrary scripts on a cloud instance (aws, digitalocean, rackspace, I'm not picky). I am not doing something shady I simply want to use it for performance testing and need reproducible results (deploy a service, set specific testdata, run the performance tests, kill everything, repeat if necessary).

Of course I can use the API of these providers and build a custom solution, but I'm wondering if there is a framework or a bunch of tools that will help me with that.

What I need is:
  - Only using an instance for the runtime of the script
  - possibility to store data outside of the instance for result analysis

There are a lot of tools to automate setting up cloud instances but they all seem targeted for deployment purposes. What I need is a cloud script runner.

Answer (score 0):

From your description is sounds like you might be looking for something like AWS's new(ish) Lambda service.

This allows you define scripts and triggers to run them in he clued without the overhead of spinning up and having to manage cloud compute 'servers'.

More info:

- https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/

One thing to be careful of when using the cloud for performance testing - you have no teal control over the actual HW that your code will run on and different runs may run on different HW. This is true even for server or instance based cloud testing.

Comment: Lambda never came to mind. I heard about it a while back but kinda forgot. The only problem is: from what I see: it only runs python and js. I already have several ruby scripts to execute.

Comment: @leifg - I'm not sure if it will meet your needs but you can launch the Ruby script from Javascript/python. From the AWS site: AWS Lambda supports code written in Node.js (JavaScript), Python, and Java (Java 8 compatible). Your code can include existing libraries, even native ones. Lambda functions can easily launch processes using languages supported by Amazon Linux, including Bash, Go, and Ruby. (https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/)